# AWS Cloudfront to EC2 with mixed PHP and static content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

This may have been asked and answered elsewhere but I could not find the exact scenario.

I have an EC2 instance running a LAMP stack and serving PHP content. This all works.

I wanted to cache this content as it doesn't often change. It's Wordpress, and Cloudfront cache speeds things up significantly. So I've set up a distribution that points to the EC2 instance.

I also have a subdirectory that is all static HTML. For example, the base URL is mysite.com serving PHP content and mysite.com/data serves HTML pages with standard index.html pages in each subdirectory.

Hitting the Cloudfront URL, the PHP content loads without fail. But hitting mysite.com/data returns the standard 502 error as if the endpoint can't be reached.

Any ideas?
Is there a better way to set this up?

Comment: Oh, and in case anyone is wondering, YES, hitting the EC2 URL/data works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The more common AWS way to set this up is to use an S3 bucket static site and a CORS-S3Origin inside of Cloudfront with a /data routing rule in front of that second origin.

I believe Cloudfront will provide example bucket policies in the web console, but getting all the permissions correct is a bit time consuming.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a spin since I've set up static content via S3/Cloudfront before.